# GTX 1080 Floating Point Performance Calculation

Tags: cuda, gpu, benchmarking, nvidia

According to Nvidia's white pages, the GTX 1080 has 2560 single-precision CUDA cores [page 5] and runs at a factory GPU boost clock setting of 1733MHz [page 9].

Doing some basic math, we can calculate floating point performance as 2560 units * 1.733 GHz clock = **4,436.48 GFLOP/s**. However, the white pages claim **8873 GFLOP/s** floating point performance [page 9], *precisely double my calculation*.

My question: where is this factor of 2 being introduced into the floating point performance calculation on Nvidia's White Pages? The white pages clearly state that the CUDA cores are single precision [page 5], so what gives?

Thanks

White pages source: http://international.download.nvidia.com/geforce-com/international/pdfs/GeForce_GTX_1080_Whitepaper_FINAL.pdf

Comment: The factor of 2 comes from [fused multiply-add](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#floating-point-instructions-fma), which counts as 2 FLOPs per instruction.